# Question in developer guide for Kafka dsl api

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I got a question when walking myself thru this awesome guide
https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html

My question is in section "Example of semantics for table aggregations". In particular, look at the table in this section, at timestamp 4, but what is the mechanism for aggregator to perform "(E, 5 - 5)".

My confusing is since the key is already transformed from name ("alice") to region ("A") at grouping step. How "groupedTable" can still sense the original key in aggregate and perform subtraction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are two mechanism in place here:

1. the base store can get the old value for a key from the store, before it puts the new value into the store
2. if required, the upstream operator hosting the base store, will send both the new and old value to the downstream operator

Comment: Thanks! But I can't correlate these mechanisms with the code provided in the guide (right above the table). I assume the table content must reflect code logic.

Comment: Not sure if I can follow. However, send old and new value is an internal implementation detail and not exposed in the API (if this was your question). The point is, internally the data flow between `userProfiles` KTable and `aggregated` KTable is no plain `KeyValue.pair(region, user.length())` as indicated in the `groupBy()`, the actual physically transferred data is a two nested pairs `<key,<newValue,oldValue>>`.

Comment: Thanks Matthias, that answered my question!Though it shall take me some time to digest its implication. Any reference to this topic is appreciated.

Comment: It's not documented because it's internal implementation details -- you can only look into the code...